# Syncing 2D audio to game map

Tags: game-engine, audio

I'm basically making a rhythm game in upbge 3.6 where the player will have to tap to the rhythm of the song. I was able to make a map for the song, but everytime I try and play it, the song is desynced to the map. I'm guessing this is because of the fps difference each time.

Could anybody suggest something that would prevent this from happening?